# Incomplete executable self-loading closures

Tags: javascript, closures, dynamic-script-loading

**Is it possible for browsers/ajax/javascript to autocomplete, and close the self-loading closures if they are left open ..?**

```
1 (function()
2 {
3 function a(n){this.name=n;}
4 var a=this;
5 //more code in here
6 alert(a);
7 //})();


- The terminating brace and parens were not present in the script i saw
- Is it possible that it must be generated dynamically, so that the .js file
- does not contain it but the script/ajax later appends it ..?
- Can the browser complete it..?
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not run some simple tests?

Use some files like this:

```
<script>
(function a () {
    alert('a');
</script>
<script>
$(function() { alert('b'); a(); });
</script>
```

This will tell you the following scenarios:

1. alerts ('a'), alerts('b'), alerts('a') ==> (unlikely): browser completed function definition and wrote closure executing parens
2. alerts('b'), alerts('a') ==> browser completed function definition and calls went as expected
3. alerts('b'), throws error for undefined a() ==> browser ignored imcomplete function defintion
4. does nothing ==> browser quit parsing after not finding a closing brace

I think it would be very unlikely that the browser would add in the executing portion of the closure, but not as unlikely that it would add in the missing end }.  Though this is definitely not a behavior you want to count on and should always form your script files nicely.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible?** Yes. Or No. Depending on what assumptions you are prepared to accept.

**Does it happen in *current* browsers?** Not that I know of, though I've never tried it.

**Is it a good idea?** No. At least, not in my opinion. I can't think of a reason why I would want this. Can you explain further why *you* would?

Take just the example you posted:

```
1 (function()
2 {
3 function a(n){this.name=n;}
4 var a=this;
5 //more code in here
6 alert(a);
7 //})();
```

So the browser sees that there is a function expression that doesn't have a closing `})`, and since a function expression like that would not actually do anything with the `();` bit on the end the browser should assume that that was intended and do that too? OK, now, at which line should it add it in? It would be valid, executable code if added just after any of lines 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6. It seems to me the most logical place to add the missing closing bracket is between lines 3 and 4, because that way the `var a` declaration wouldn't clash with the `function a` definition. Do you want the browser to figure that sort of thing out?

Should the browser work on a "greedy" basis and include as much as possible in the outer function? As little as possible? Because you could bet that IE would go "greedy", FF would go minimal, Chrome would do a web search to find a similar but complete script on another page and use the complete one instead, and Opera would just report it as an error and not run it.